# How to change css with php in wordpress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, project-management, buddypress

I’m very new to php coding and I’ve been trying very hard to get this to work.

I’m using wedevs project management plugin with buddy press integration. There dev team doesn’t have the time to customize the plugin for me at the moment so I’m looking for a quick fix. I feel I’m so close but for some reason I’m not getting it to work.

I have a “create project” button that I would like to hide for all group members accept the Group admin. so I would like it to verify if the user is the group admin and show the “create project link”. But if it is just a group member or user, I would like the “create project link” to be hidden. Only group admins should be allowed to create projects… Here is what I have so far. But its not working. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php if ( BP_Groups_Member::get_is_admin_of( $user_id )) { ?>
    <style  type="text/css" media="screen">
    .cpm-projects nav.cpm-new-project a {visibility:visible; }
    </style>
<?php } else { ?>
   <style  type="text/css" media="screen">
   .cpm-projects nav.cpm-new-project a {visibility:hidden; }
   </style>
<?php } ?>
```

Keep in mind that the stylesheet for the plugin has this inside the style sheet.

```
.cpm-projects nav.cpm-new-project a {
    background: transparent url("../images/plus.png") no-repeat scroll 50% 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

For some reason its still showing for all members with this code.

I’ve tried all of these calls and still nothing

```
if ( BP_Groups_Member::get_is_admin_of( $user_id )) {

if ( ! groups_is_user_admin( $user_id, $group_id ) ) {

if ( groups_is_user_admin( $user_id, $group_id ) ) {

if ( groups_is_user_admin( get_current_user_id(), $group_id ) ) {
```

Comment: Is it within the `<head>` block of your page?

Comment: where is the function groups_is_admin_admin()? What is the return value of that function? You seem unsure how to call it. Is it a static function? More info please.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it fixes your problem, but a cleaner way is to put the CSS code as two separate classes into your custom CSS file. In other words, you hide the button with CSS for all users by default, but then create a class ".can_create_proj" to show the button for the admin.

In your PHP code, you can add the class name to the button if the current user is admin.

```
<nav class = "cpm-new-project">
    <a clas="<?php check_is_admin( $user_id, $group_id ) ? echo "can_create_proj"; ?>">Create Project</a>
</nav>
```

Maybe using check_is_admin( $user_id, $group_id ) will work. Ref: https://buddypress.org/support/topic/checking-if-member-is-also-a-group-admin/

In you CSS:

```
nav.cpm-new-project a {
    display:block;
}

.can_create_proj {
    display:none;
}
```